# Dynamic directory authorisation asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, directory, authorization

My site is using forms authentication with both users and roles.
I use small web.config files to deny/allow access to directories for specific users or roles.

Those file look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admins, Coaches, Athletes"/>
        <deny users="*, ?"/>
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The above works.

My site has two groups of users; athletes and coaches.The configuration of which user is a coach of which athlete is done in the database.

I now need to create the following:
My site will generate athlete specific reports. Those reports should only be visible for that specify athlete and also to his/her coach. Each athlete will get its own directory on the server.

To accomplish this i could place a web.config file into each directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <allow users="AthleteName"/>
        <allow users="CoachName"/>
        <deny users="*, ?"/>
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This would probably work. My problem is:
New users can be added to the site at any time through a membership page. 
The coach/athlete configuration is done in the database and can change at any time. It can also change through a back-end system which is not part of my site.

Instead of having a static web.config i was looking for a more dynamic way of access authorisation to directories.
Does anybody have a good idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration()` to write in web.config at runtime.

Example:

```
Dim myConfiguration As Configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~")
myConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("myKey").Value = myNewVaule
myConfiguration.Save()
```

IIS should detects when `web.config` changes but I am not sure if changes in `urlAuthorizationModule` configuration happens instantly.

Anyway, you could use ASP.NET membership. In [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) you can see how use and configure it. ASP.NET membership roles integrates with urlAuthorizationModule so you can create a new user in BD with roles and keep  `<allow roles="Admins, Coaches, Athletes"/>` for resource authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! here is a link to the related msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx